# Whats wrong with setting this path variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have adb binary  in `~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/`. I created a symlink of adb binary  to `/usr/local/sbin/`. I can execute adb from both the specified directories:

```
aswin@Tron:/usr/local/sbin$ sudo ./adb shell
[sudo] password for aswin:
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
root@android:/ #
```

but,

```
aswin@Tron:/usr/local/sbin$ sudo sh adb shell
adb: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I added both to `$PATH` by : `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin/:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/` and added the lines to `~/.bashrc`

```
aswin@Tron:/usr/local/sbin$ echo "$PATH"
/home/aswin/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin/:/home/aswin/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
```

but when I try to execute:

```
aswin@Tron:~$ ./adb shell
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

whats the problem? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Run `file ./adb` and `ldd ./adb` and show us the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correct you have two question here.  First:

```
aswin@Tron:/usr/local/sbin$ sudo sh adb shell
adb: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

You are attempting to execute a binary using `sh` which is causing this error.  Simply saying `sudo adb shell` would work provided `adb` exists in the `PATH` of the `sudo` environment.

Second:

```
aswin@Tron:~$ ./adb shell
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

After adding the directory containing `adb` to `PATH`, you need to execute it by saying:

```
adb shell
```

You are saying `./adb ...` which would work only if `adb` exists in the current working directory.